# how to show "hello world" backbone-marionette.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views

I am trying to trying a view using backbone +backbone-marionette.js..But I am able to get alert in route .But I want to display a view .But I am not able to display my template ?could you please tell me how to show my first view in angular

http://goo.gl/9YE0H8

```
var firstpage = Backbone.View.extend({
template:"template/firstpage"
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many things you have to look at, to display that simple message.

this will initiate the router on document ready.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    router = new routers();
    Backbone.history.start();
})
```

Now in router function  we will **initialize** our View and append it to body

```
showFirstPage:function(){
     var fView = new firstpage(); // view initialized
     $('body').append(fView.el);  
    }
```

el contains all the events and html , read about it [**here**](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el)

For this to work we have to set some html to **el** of view on initialize

```
var firstpage = Backbone.View.extend({
template:_.template("<h1>Hello World<h1>"),
initialize:function(){
    this.$el.html(this.tempalte());
}
})
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JQu5Q/15/)

Comment: But it is not working please check i used your solution here http://goo.gl/Z1N0o8

Comment: change the order of scripts load view first and then router and copy the view exactly as it is from the answer .it will work , worked for me

Comment: yes..got it..please look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28023451/how-to-load-html-file-in-marionette-js-backbone

Comment: could you please look my another Question I need to load a view using marionettejs

Comment: @user944513 hope i would help you but i am not aware of marionette :(