# how to load html file in Marionette .js + backbone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views

I have one "test.html" in that I have this contend (whole html file have this contend).

```
<h1>First page</h1>
```

I need to load that contend in my div having id ="contend" using  Marionette .js

```
<div id="contend">


    </div>
```

could you please tell me how I will do that ?
fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/JQu5Q/16/

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
            var ContactManager = new Marionette.Application();
            ContactManager.addRegions({
                mainRegion:"#contend"
            })

            ContactManager.on("start", function(){
                console.log("ContactManager has started!");


            });

            ContactManager.start();

         // router 
             var routers =  Backbone.Router.extend({
            routes: {
                "": "showFirstPage"
            },
            showFirstPage:function(){

            }
            })

             var ToolItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({

                template: '<div>hello</div>',



            });

        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show the view by Backbone.router, you just need to pass the Marionette app to router than show it.

```
var routers = new Router({app: ContactManager})
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JQu5Q/19/)

Comment: could you please look this Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28038445/how-to-load-precomplied-template-in-backbone

Comment: @sir please I need to load html file which is on directory

Comment: did you find solution??

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate the view, and show it in the region:

```
var toolItemview = new ToolItemView(); 
ContactManager.mainRegion.show(toolItemview);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JQu5Q/17/