# why html is not loaded while using backbone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-events

I trying to load my html page using backbone framework .I am using backbone-marionettejs file.I need to show load my my template while using router functionalty in backbone .could you please tell me where i did wrong ? here is my code

http://goo.gl/cnrE7c

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tut</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <!--script type="text/javascript" src="lib/json2.js"></script-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/underscore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/backbone.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/backbone.marionette.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="router/router.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="view/first.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <div id="header">

    </div>
    <div id="contend">
        <p>Here is static content in the web page. You'll notice that it gets
             replaced by our app as soon as we start it.</p>

    </div>
    <div id="fotter">

    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="view/first.js"></script>
</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var ContactManager = new Marionette.Application();
        ContactManager.addRegions({
            mainRegion:"#contend"
        })

        ContactManager.on("start", function(){
            console.log("ContactManager has started!");


        });

        ContactManager.start();

    })


</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are you changing the content?

Comment: actulally I need to change contend on router.js file

Comment: it seems like you ask the same question. I answer it [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28023451/how-to-load-html-file-in-marionette-js-backbone/28038539#28038539](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28023451/how-to-load-html-file-in-marionette-js-backbone/28038539#28038539). Hope to help you.

Comment: could you please look this Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28038445/how-to-load-precomplied-template-in-backbone