# how to load precomplied template in backbone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views

could you please tell me how to load precomplied templates .I googled it and find a solution .Now I don't know how to use this function.could you please tell me how to use this function ?
code:
http://goo.gl/ALfkzf

```
Backbone.Marionette.TemplateCache.prototype.loadTemplate = function (templateId, callback) {
            var tmpId = templateId.replace("#", ""),
                    url = "/app/templates/" + tmpId + ".html";

            $.get(url, function (templateHtml) {
                compiledTemplate = Handlebars.compile($(templateHtml).html())
                callback.call(this, compiledTemplate);
            });
        };

        Backbone.Marionette.Renderer.renderTemplate = function (templateId, data) {
            var renderer = $.Deferred();
            Backbone.Marionette.TemplateCache.get(templateId, function(template){
                var html = template(data);
                renderer.resolve(html);
            });
            return renderer.promise();
        };
```

I am trying to load html file which is inside the directory ? template/test.html

var ToolItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({

```
    template: 'template/test.html',



});
```

Comment: using this I will create a dependency of Handlebars.js could I load another way a template

Answer (score 0):

The code that you are trying to use, replaces default HTML mechanism in Marionette.

1. 'template/test.html' will be translated to "/app/templates/template/test.html.html", which I guess is not what you want (Either change url generation, or template pointer)
2. Your Backbone code, does not assume, that "test.html" was precompiled on contrary compilation is happening on the client, following GET response, is this what you want?
3. Regarding Backbone override use, it should be called before you try to render your ToolItemView, so basically you can call this code anywhere before ToolItemView render.

Comment: wait I do some thing could you please change on that code

Comment: please http://goo.gl/LGUEBv this I do more .I don't get any error still page is not load

Comment: Do you know how to use Firebug or Chrome Development tools at all?

Comment: The link you give shows, only part of the code. I see "Uncaught ReferenceError: render is not defined", I would suggest you to learn to use Development Tools, before writing anything or asking questions.

Comment: sorry sir ...http://goo.gl/OrGjRZ ..Actually I already defined render function..I know that I am getting error but I defined render function on script tag

Comment: You need to move your render definition as a first script statement, after loading JQuery. Exception is happening before html reached render

Comment: But How I will upload my html view which is inside the template folder

Comment: I'm not familiar with the platform you are using. I'm not sure it's possible there. Look at Network requests, and go from there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69182/discussion-between-pallavi-sharma-and-mavarazy).